# Notepad++ Regex Backreference missing

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++, backreference

I have this HTML part :

```
<a href="http://always-same-path.to/my/file.pdf">Random reference</a>
```

This line exists in a lot of files.

I need to replace it with :

```
Random reference <lots>of tags</lots>
```

**The usual regex (Ctrl + F) works well. Unfortunately, the replacement text is way too long and can't be used in the usual regex, so I used TextFX's advanced Search and replace plugin.**

This is my find:

```
<a href="http://always-same-path.to/my/file.pdf">(.+)</a>
```

This is my replace:

```
\1 <lots>of tags</lots>
```

**Finding works (i.e. the line is highlighted)**
Replacing, however, doesn't. 
I get this instead :

```
<lots>of tags</lots>
```

Those options are checked in the Find/replace window:

- Regular Expr
- Autograb Find Text
- Wrap

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you should use $1 instead of \1 ? Or try 0 instead of 1.

Comment: $1 doesn't work, \0 neither. Thanks though !

Comment: I just tried on my Notepad++, simply pressed ctrl+H and used your pattern and replace string. Pressed 'replace all' and everything worked fine.

Comment: As I stated, it actually works in the "Ctrl+H" or "Ctrl+F" window. But I can't use it in this window because the replacement string is too long. So I use Advanced Find/Replace (TextFX Plugin). Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me. I've just to select all (`CTRL+A`) before doing the replace.

Comment: is your find grabbing the text properly?

Comment: Yes, as stated "Finding works (i.e. the line is highlighted)". Thanks !

Comment: @Flipke, use a tool that works, eg `perl -pi.b -e "s,<a href="http://always-same-path.to/my/file.pdf">(.+)</a>,$1 <lots>of tags</lots>,g" myfile.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue for me, but resolved!

I just used in the replace field `$0` and it worked !

My Notepad++ version: v6.1.5 UNICODE  (just updated! - I would suggest you to do the same)

File format I'm working on: `.srt` (movie subtitles)

"Find What" field: `^\d+$` [matching line with just a number]

"Replace with" field:   `----- $0 ------`

Comment: wow. this is really annoying. what happened to $1? and \1?  seems like this changes every release. +1... for your answer!  thanks.